# How to get characters input in keyboard while playing a game using python?

Tags: python, input, character

I am making an AI to drive cars in GTA San Andreas using Tensorflow and I want to know which characters/keys are pressed at each frame using python. I cannot use `input()` cause my program is not in front. What I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pyHook](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/) might be something you might be looking for. All the keyboard or mouse events can be captured using Windows hooks. `pyhook` is a Python wrapper around the hooks API.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33864704/544787) presents a sample code for using `pyhook` to capture the keypress. [This document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) provides with basics of Hook in Windows.

Below is an example, which hooks for keyboard events and prints the key pressed to console. It exits on keypress for `x` or `X`.

```
#!python

import pythoncom, pyHook
import sys

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    # block only the letter A, lower and uppercase
    print chr(event.Ascii)
    if event.Ascii in (ord('x'), ord('X')):
        sys.exit()
    # returning True to pass on event to other applications
    return True

# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
# watch for all mouse events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()
# wait forever
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: I think this will work, but can you give me a better explanation than in the link? Could you please just write the code to repeatedly print the pressed character?