# How to make smart keyboard mapping with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

I want to make a smart keyboard layout on Windows with Python that determines the letter to be typed when a key is hit, after processing is done by the program. I am wondering which libraries and functions to use in order to first read the initial keypress, block its initial output, and then simulate the keystroke that the program determines is best. I have been having the most difficulty finding a library that can both read and then stop a keystroke from being typed.

Comment: The only module in that direction I know of is `pynput`. Other than that this answer has some insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863921/detecting-a-keypress-in-python-while-in-the-background/33864704

Comment: @Dschoni I have tried using pynput, but I was not able to find a way to block the initial keystroke. Please let me know if you know of a way to do this.

Comment: I remember reading something here: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/22 and here: https://python.developreference.com/article/27429135/Python+disable+redirect+keyboard+input