# How to stop a python program when auto clicking away from the IDE?

Tags: python

I have a python program that takes control of the mouse. However, I would like to be able to cancel the program from running without wrestling the mouse away from the program. I tried to cancel using a keyboard shortcut like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

However, this has the same issue, once the program has clicked away from the IDE I am unable to stop the program without fighting against the mouse. Is this even possible?

Comment: Could you clarify *auto clicking away from IDE*?  Auto prefix means self.

Comment: What are you using for the UI of the application? In general you'll be limited to what events that interface can provide about focus events.

Comment: You can stop the script on some keypress. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863921/detecting-a-keypress-in-python-while-in-the-background)

Comment: @MatsLindh I am running it directly from PyCharm, this is not a production app.

Comment: @RazzleShazl in ```main``` I am using the ```payautogui``` to control the mouse so the IDE is no longer the main focus of the os, therefor pressing ctrl-c won't stop the program

Comment: Using the linked question from Yevhen you can listen for keypresses regardless of pycharm having focus; if you're on Windows that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fail-safes) it looks like you can configure a failsafe.

> As a safety feature, a fail-safe feature is enabled by default. When a
> PyAutoGUI function is called, if the mouse is in any of the four
> corners of the primary monitor, they will raise a
> pyautogui.FailSafeException. There is a one-tenth second delay after
> calling every PyAutoGUI functions to give the user time to slam the
> mouse into a corner to trigger the fail safe.

Fail safe appears to be enabled by default.  Verify that `pyautogui.FAILSAFE == True`.

In code: Try changing `KeyboardInterrupt` to `pyautogui.FailSafeException`.

At runtime: Within `.1s` of your program calling a `pyautogui` function, move your mouse to the corner of your screen.  I expect this to trigger your `sys.exit(0)`.

Comment: This will buy you `.1s` -- how fast of a gunslinger are you with a mouse, cowboy?