# How to listen to pressed keys of a google Chrome Application/Window

Tags: python, pynput

i want a bot who prints the keys witch are pressed in google chrome youtube (in the search-bar). But the Code works only with keys like space, enter etc and not with 'a', 'b' etc. Here the code:

```
import win32gui
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
 try: key_pressed = key.char # single-char keys
 except: key_pressed = key.name # other keys
 print(key_pressed)
 active_window = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
 print(active_window)
```

Any Help would be apreceated (my english is not very good). Beacause every time i go on google chrome it dont recognise the keys. Please help-

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this post.
It has a lot of good content on listening to keys using Python:

[Detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

## EDIT:

If you want it in the background while on some other app check this:

[Detecting a keypress in python while in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863921/detecting-a-keypress-in-python-while-in-the-background/33864704)

Sarthak Jain

Comment: Yeah, but if im not on the script it wont detected the keys, but thanks

Comment: Check the new edit. Tell me if that helps.